# Flash Danger message is appearing twice only on Login view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please take a look at the image at this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mL5y.png to see exactly what I am talking about.

I have a flash[:danger] message for invalid login that is appearing twice only my Login view. However, I don't know where the plain text message (the duplication) is coming from. I can only find it when I use FireFox inspect element.

I am using AWS Cloud and I have looked over my Login controller and model, my custom.scss file, my Login view and, even my routes.rb (just in case). There is nothing that would show the flash message again.

My flash is used only in the create action for my Login controller.

Here is what is I see when I inspect the element using FireFox:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="alert alert-danger">Invalid email/password combination</div>
    Invalid email/password combination **<---This is the oddity**
</div>
```

My Login controller:

```
def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      # Log the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
    else
      flash[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination' **<--Only here**
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Below is what is in my Login view:

```
<% provide(:title, "Log in") %>
<h1>Log in</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unless I am missing something, the duplication should not be appearing. I have used flash for another part of my web app and I did not have this problem. I am only expecting to see the text within the alert div and not the duplication as well.

Any advice on how to stop that duplication will be appreciated.

This is an image of what I am talking about. What is below that red box is my issue:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mL5y.png

As requested by Mr. Pandey, below is the contents of my application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= render 'layouts/rails_default' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>

  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header'%>
      <div class="container">
      <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
        <%= content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}") %>
          <%= message %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you using devise for authentication?

Comment: Hello Vishal, I am unsure what you are asking. Would you re-phrase it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
  <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
    <%= content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-# 
  {message_type}") %>
      <%= message %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

with

```
<% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
  <%= content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}") %>
<% end %>
```

The below `flash` is due to `<%= message %>` one

Comment: Hello Mr. Pandey, thank you for your response. That is not exactly what I am referring to so I added an image to my post that shows my issue. If you can provide any guidance, it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you show your application.html.erb file inside layout and file where you are showing flash message

Comment: I have added my application.html.erb to the bottom of my post. I see that there is a call to flash within it as well. However, if I take that one out of my application.html.erb, my flash message does not show. But it seems that, because I have a flash message in my controller and in my application view, both flash messages are showing. How would I get solve this, where only one flash message is showing?

Comment: So, just to re-cap, there is a call to flash within my application.html.erb and within my Login controller. Both are within my post.

Comment: OH! Thank you very much!